# What is enumerate in Python mean?

Tags: python, enumerated-types

What is `<enumerate object at 0x000000000302E2D0>` mean?

> `>>> my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'pear']`
>   `>>> enumerate(my_list)`
>   `<enumerate object at 0x000000000302E2D0>`

I try Google and still don't understand why we have `<enumerate object at 0x000000000302E2D0>`. Can you help me with this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Related to, if not exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24260582/1639625)

Answer (score 2):

It returns an *enumerate object*, which is an iterator.  It does not actually show you what it contains until you specifically ask it to. One way to do this is to force it to be a list.

```
>>> my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'pear']
>>> a = enumerate(my_list)
>>> a
<enumerate at 0x7ffff27d0630>
>>> list(a)
[(0, 'apple'), (1, 'banana'), (2, 'grapes'), (3, 'pear')]
```

You can also iterate over an enumerate object in a for loop.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols) for more information about iterators.

Answer (score 1):

From `enumerate.__doc__`:

```
enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable

Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
    (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```